# C++, expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

I am not very good with C++ arrays, my code:

```
int sum[100][100][100][100];

int main(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
            for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) 
                for (int l = 0; l < 100; l++) 
                    sum[i][j][k][l] = -1024;
}
```

, and I got the error on the line that said "sum[i][j][k][l] = -1024;" under the variable i

I have no idea why this happened, and my help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/o4xVSj

Comment: The code you have posted does not have any errors. Please make sure you posted the exact code that gave you the error, and also post the exact text of the error messages.

Comment: FYI, this error happens when you try to use array access on something that isn't an array. The code you posted compiles fine, but the error you got probably came from a typo like only a three-level `int sum[100][100][100];`

Comment: If your code has any `#include`s it's possible a macro is messing something up. The code is fine otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

Where is the return ? you forgot it...

You seem to be on C instead of C++ too because C89 and earlier versions only support declaration statements at the head of a block

Comment: C++ supports `for (int i = `... , and omitting the return statement for `main` is equivalent to having `return 0;` .